# Discord.py | Image not sending

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a nsfw cmd for my discord bot.
Summary:
Selects random file from folder, then attachs it to an embed and sends it.

Here is my code:

```
fp = random.choice(os.listdir('NSFW/Ass/'))
await ctx.send(file = discord.File('NSFW/Ass/%s' % (fp)), embed = discord.Embed(title = None, description = None, colour = 0xaa00ff))
```

It outputs this:
https://jokers.has-no-bra.in/oEVtd1
I want it to output:
Something like this :https://jokers.has-no-bra.in/NxSkKF

Comment: I tried this to, embed.set_image(url = 'attachment://NSFW/Ass/%s.png' % (fp)) but it outputs an embed with no image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking an image, you need to give it a name (`image.png` is good enough, it doesn't have to be the real name of the file), and then refer to it as `attachment://name`.

```
embed = discord.Embed()
file = discord.File(path_to_your_file, filename="image.png")
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    fp = random.choice(os.listdir('NSFW'))
    file = discord.File(f"NSFW/{fp}", filename="image.png")

    e = discord.Embed()
    e.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
    await ctx.send(embed=e, file=file)
```

Note that the filename in the File constructor and the filename in the URL must match.